# Can ADO.NET Data Services use named pipes as a transport

Tags: .net, wcf, ado.net, rest

I am well aware that the Rest based approach is targeting HTTP.  I would love to use the REST APIs and other goodness between processes on the same computer.  Since ADO.NET data services is built on top of WCF it would seem reasonable to assume that the transport in configurable to work with any of the WCF supported transports.  Anyone know if there is a way to configure it to send traffic via namedpipes?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the REST architectural style does not in any way require HTTP.  That just happens to be the most common implementation protocol. However, ADO.Net data services uses System.ServiceModel.Web which IS tied to http.
You can certainly do REST over named pipes, you will just have to find a different protocol.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 3.5 there is built-in named pipe binding for WCF. See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) for details.